# Reading XML File - Binding TextBlock in ListBox Windows phone 8.1 and move an item to a separate string variable

Tags: c#

I am reading from xml file and displaying a selected item in a ListBox that is binding elements in a TextBlock. But now I want to extract a string that is displayed so that it can be converted to speech. I have a text-to-speech button that must read the contents displayed by the ListBox, but it ends up reading/ playing this:
System.Linq.Enumerable+whereSelectEnumerableIterator2[System.XML.Linq.XElement,Sleepy_Time_Stories.StroryPage+InspirationMsg]

Here's my code that reads and displays in xaml binded ListBox:

```
 XDocument LoadData = XDocument.Load("Stories.xml"); //xml file name
        var SearchData = from c in LoadData.Descendants("Messg")//xml tags
                         where c.Attribute("Story").Value == (string)e.Parameter
                         select new InspirationalMsg()
                         {

                             InspMessage = c.Attribute("InspMessage").Value,

                         };

        displayMsg.ItemsSource = SearchData; // displaying in ListBox
        txResult.Text = SearchData.ToString();
        displayMsg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public class InspirationalMsg
    {
        string story;
        string msg;
        int id;

        public string Story
        {
            get { return story; }
            set { story = value; }
        }

        public string InspMessage
        {
            get { return msg; }
            set { msg = value; }
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

    }
```

## This is the xaml code for the list box:

```
<ListBox x:Name="displayMsg" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Medium" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="400" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="12,17,0,28" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding InspMessage}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="txStory" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#003366" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ListBox.Background>
    </ListBox>
    <Button x:Name="btnPlay" Content="Play for Me" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,546,0,0"    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="157" Tapped="btnPlay_Tapped" Click="btnPlay_Click"/>
    <Button  x:Name="btnStop" Content="Stop" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,546,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174" Tapped="btnStop_Tapped"/>
```

This is the XML File:

```
    <Messg
     Story="Stay blessed"
       InspMessage="Your help does not come from what you have or don’t have nor what you know or        don’t know. Your help comes from the Lord, the Lord which made Heaven and earth (scripture verse: Psalm 121:2)."
     Id="1" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom class which defines your what you want to display on Listbox. In that class, add override function ToString() which convert data into string format. Then you can dedicate list of your class to ItemSource of Listbox
You can find details on below link [Binding a control to a collection of objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207023(v=vs.105).aspx) 
Hope it to help on your issue.

Peter